# What are the proper properties for Kafka connector when using Oracle DB

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am learning about Kafka Connect and would like to use Oracle as my database.

I am having trouble with the properties.
[image]

Is there any setting/property that I am missing in order to fix this error?

Comment: Please can you post the actual text, not a screenshot. As an image it makes it harder for people to read, and also cannot be searched by people in the future. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/index.html#install-connector-manually):

> The JDBC source and sink connectors use the Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) API that enables applications to connect to and use a wide range of database systems. In order for this to work, the connectors must have a JDBC Driver for the particular database systems you will use.

So in your case you have to [install](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/index.html#oracle-database) Oracle Database driver.